# Match mySQL with any word in string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, match, sql-like

```
SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE Name LIKE '%{$_GET["searchval"]}%'
```

The above code will return all entries in the Restaurants table where the name field contains the searchval.

For example, if the searchval was "Example Entry" and the database had an entry with the name "Example Entry Number Five", that entry would display. But, if the entry was "Example Number Five" it would not display.

How can I make it such that if the database entry contains any one word in the string, it will display. Such that "Example Entry" would display if the entry had "Example" or "Entry" in it.

Comment: Split your searchval in to words and add a LIKE clause for each WHERE name like '%word1%' OR name like '%word2%' etc. You can also have a look at full text search

Comment: @Juan but how could that be done programmatically and dynamically based on whatever an end user inputs?

Comment: You are looking for [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Well, which language are you using to build your query? In .Net you can use string.Split and the iterate over the array it returns to build the right query

Comment: You should look into full text indexing.

Comment: Seems like OP is using PHP given that he is echoing `$_GET` directly into the query string. Which is anyway, **a very bad idea**. You have to either sanitize your inputs, or use prepared statements. Just split up your query string by a separator (like a whitespace character), prepend "LIKE" to each element and then join the array using "OR".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution are full text indexes.  However, you can do what you want using regular expressions.

Assuming that words are separated by only one word, you can do:

```
where name rlike replace({$_GET["searchval"]}, ' ', '|')
```

If you really want to take the regular expressions approach, I would suggest that you do the value parsing in the application layer.  But, this does do what you want in the database, assuming that words are separated by a space and not using special regular expression characters.

Comment: Thanks! I used PHP to replace spaces with |'s in the string, returning the 'Example|Entry' needed for rlike. I also sanitized the input for those who got alarmed.